# store html in python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, lxml, lxml.html

I'm using both xpath and beautifulsoup to scrape webpage. 
Xpath need tree as input and beautifulsoup need soup as input.
Here're the code to get tree and soup:

```
def get_tree(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    tree = html.fromstring(r.content)
    return tree

# get soup
def get_soup(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    data = r.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
    return soup
```

Both of these method uses requests.get(url). That's what I want to store ahead.
Here's the code in python:

```
import requests
url = "http://www.nytimes.com/roomfordebate/2013/10/28/should-you-bribe-your-kids"
r = requests.get(url)
f = open('html','wb')
f.write(r)
```

And then I got error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: must be convertible to a buffer, not Response
```

Here's the code to store the text, and I got error:

```
import requests
from lxml import html
url = "http://www.nytimes.com/roomfordebate/2013/02/13/when-divorce-is-a-family-affair"
r = requests.get(url)
c = r.content
outfile = open("html", "wb")
outfile.write(c)
outfile.close()
infile = open("html", "rb")
tree = html.fromstring(infile)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 662, in fromstring
    start = html[:10].lstrip().lower()
TypeError: 'file' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

How could I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
infile = open("html", "rb") #this is a file object Not a string
```

You need to read it first with `read()` and not just open :-)-

```
infile = open("html", "rb")
infile=infile.read()
tree = html.fromstring(infile)
```

Answer (score 0):

requests.get returns a response object.

I guess the write wants text.  What you want is the response's contents, which is also text.

```
r = requests.get(url).content
```

Comment: Thanks. I still got the error when loading the content. See update post.

Answer (score 0):

`fromstring()` expects a string as an input. Since you have a file, you need to use [`parse()`](http://lxml.de/parsing.html#parsers):

```
>>> tree = html.parse(infile)
>>> tree.findtext('//title')
When Divorce Is a Family Affair - Room for Debate - NYTimes.com
```